# Pass data between two VC

Tags: ios, swift, properties, segue

I am new to the Swift world. I am learning how to pass data from `VCa` (TableView) to `VCb` using the `prepare segue` method. I would like to know how should I declare the business property from my second view controller since `destinationVC.business` is of type Business. When I declared a var `business: business` in the second view controller I am getting an initialize error. How should I declare my business property?

Thanks for all the answers and explanations.

First view controller

```
var businesses: [Business]
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "GoToDiscoverDetail" {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let business = businesses[indexPath.row]
                let destinationVC = segue.destination as! DiscoverDetailViewController
//                destinationVC.business = business

            }

        }
    }
```

Second view controller 
I declared a var

```
var business: businesses
```

Comment: You can give it a default value like this `var business = Business()` or you can make it an optional `var business: Business?` in which case it will be `nil` until you assign your value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to make it an optional it’s working. But I can not do var business = Business() since Business have some argument. When I tried it, i am always getting cannot invoke initializer for type Business with no arguments. Is there a work around to this way. Trying to learn all tips.

Comment: If your class is complicated and doesn't have a basic default, then the optional is the way to go.  The non-optional route works best for basic types like `Int` and `String` that have reasonable default values like `0` and `""`.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this issue. I can get the result. Please check if this is working for you.

**In FirstViewController:**

```
var business:[Business]? = []
```

**In SecondViewController:**

```
var business: Business?
```

**Segue**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "GoToDiscoverDetail" {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let business = businesses?[indexPath.row]
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! DiscoverDetailViewController
            destinationVC.business = business

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes what I do as the last solution to pass data between VCs that always works perfectly for me is to use an in-app notification. You can apply it to your scenario as you wish but here are the basics to it:

1. Create a separate Swift file to add your notification names

   ```
     import Foundation

      extension Notification.Name {

     static let yourNotification = Notification.Name("com.appName.notification.yourNotification")

    }
   ```
2. Add your notification to pass the data to another view inside of your function

   ```
   NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .yourNotification, object: nil, userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]?) // in the userInfo you just add your data as a key-value pair so for example ["business" : business]
   ```
3. Inside of the viewDidLoad of the other VC you must add an observer

   ```
   NotificationCenter.defualt.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(yourNotificationFunction(_:)), name: .yourNotification, object: nil)
   ```
4. In the second VC you create a function to do something with the data you passed and retrieve it

   ```
   @objc func yourNotificationFunction(_ notification: NSNotification) {

   if let business = notification.userInfo?["business"] as? [String] {
      //do something with your data you passed
     }

   }
   ```

   You just have to modify it to work the way that you want to; there are many possibilities, but I find it as a very effective way to easily pass data between VCs.

Answer (score 0):

**FirstViewController:**

```
var business:[Business]? = []
```

**SecondViewController:**

```
var business: Business?
```

Answer (score -1):

Declare the business property in your second view controller (DiscoverDetailViewController) as optional (@vacawama commented the same)

```
var business: Business?
```